# Remove Header and Footer as per Config Settings in Custom Module

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0, page-layouts

using Magento 1.9,

Can anyone let me know that how can i remove, header or footer as per config settings for my custom module.

I tried below but not working:

```
<mymodule_index_index>
        <remove name="header" ifconfig="general/layout/enable" />
        <remove name="footer" ifconfig="general/layout/enable" />
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mymodule/mymodule" name="mymodule" template="mymodule/mymodule.phtml"/>
        </reference>
 </mymodule>
```

Comment: `ifconfig` is only processed as an `action` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="general/layout/enable">
       <child>header</child>
    </action>
    <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="general/layout/enable">
       <child>footer</child>
    </action>
</reference>
```

I'm not sure if that is where your error lies - more specifics on what isn't working may help. Just in case, make sure you are referring to the correct admin config setting.

Comment: See [`Mage_Core_Model_Layout ::_generateAction()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L290-L296) for understanding.